# Recipe of/for a dish, the difference

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What is the difference in meanings between "a recipe for bread" and "of bread"?

The second variant comes up in expressions like "a recipe of love/success/happiness", "a plain recipe of agar".

Comment: "Recipe **of**" describes the _components_ or _ingredients_ in a recipe: _"Its recipe **of** brandy, myrrh, and cayenne indicates it would indeed promote a heat..."_ Recipe **for**" describes the end result of the recipe: _"A recipe **for** mulled brandy."_ It is common even for native speakers to confuse the two usages.

Comment: A recipe for leek soup = how to cook leek soup, a recipe of leek soup, ... = leek soup is one of the ingredients of the dish. Right?

Comment: Erm..yes, sort of. _"A recipe **of** leeks, milk, salt and pepper yields leek soup."_  ...  _"A recipe **for** leek soup is: add leeks, milk, salt, and pepper to a pot and simmer."_ **Of** describes the ingredients. **For** describes the end product.

Comment: An ingredient would be one of the leeks, milk, salt, or pepper in the recipe. We could say those are all ingredients **of** the recipe **for** leek soup. Does that help?

Comment: Ok. A recipe for roast chicken describes what ingredients should be taken and how to process them to cook roast chicken. A recipe of roast chicken, a bottle of red wine and a good movie yields a lovely evening at home. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

"Recipe of" describes the components or ingredients in a recipe: "Its recipe of brandy, myrrh, and cayenne indicates it would indeed promote a heat..." Recipe for" describes the end result of the recipe: "A recipe for mulled brandy." It is common even for native speakers to confuse the two usages.

"A recipe of leeks, milk, salt and pepper yields leek soup." ... "A recipe for leek soup is: add leeks, milk, salt, and pepper to a pot and simmer." *Of describes the ingredients. For describes the end product*.
[P E Dant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/37009/p-e-dant)

or more poetically:

A recipe for roast chicken describes what ingredients should be taken and how to process them to cook roast chicken. A recipe of roast chicken, a bottle of red wine and a good movie yields a lovely evening at home. [Yulia](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/44895/yulia)

Comment: The last paragraph is mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

"a recipe for bread" means that it's a recipe designed well with regard to using bread. That is what "for" means as a preposition. It's something for the benefit of something else.

**EXAMPLES**

1. I can pay rent *for* you. (I will do it at your benefit - *for you*)
2. I can talk to someone *for* you. (I will translate on your behalf - *for you*)
3. You are the right person *for* the job. (you are best person to do the job - *for the job*)

"of bread" means that it's a recipe that is actually made into bread, or with bread, or from bread. The preposition "of" represents parts of something related to something else.

**EXAMPLES**

1. A cake is made of batter (it's made with batter)
2. A soda is made of sugar water (it's made with sugar and water)
3. A building is made of massive concrete slabs. (the building is constructed with concrete slabs - it's "made of concrete")

---

The variant you mention is a metaphor and means something similar to: "it's a recipe which is like happiness". For example, the idea or thought of it, or performing it, makes you happy. It's just a way to another idea. Basically a way to say it's something that makes you happy. Just like, "a recipe for success" would be a metaphor to mean it's a recipe which will lead to success.

Comment: Thank you. Am I right supposing that "a recipe for leek soup" means a set of instructions and ingredients which are necessary for making leek soup? And what does "a plain recipe of agar" mean? A way of using agar?

Comment: @Yulia See my comment above.

Comment: @Yulia Yes, that's correct :) I'm not sure about the second question. I don't know the full context. It sounds like made with the agar substance.